# pyspark tag first observation groupby window function

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to create a new column in my pyspark dataframe that is equal to one if that row is the last row in a groupby using some sorting. My solution works but seems very hacky:

My strategy was to create random numbers and (using a window function) identify the last random number per sorted group and finally compare that in a case when:

```py
df = (df.withColumn('rand', rand())
        .withColumn("marker",
         F.when(F.last(col('rand'))
                 .over(Window.partitionBy(['bvdidnumber','dt_year'])
                 .orderBy(["dt_rfrnc"]).rowsBetween(0,sys.maxsize))
              == col('rand'),1).otherwise(0))
        .drop('rand'))
```

The first three columns are the input data, the last column is created using the code, `goals` is the target to be achieved.

```
+-----------+-------+--------+----+------+
|bvdidnumber|dt_year|dt_rfrnc|goal|marker|
+-----------+-------+--------+----+------+
|          1|   2020|  202006|   0|     0|
|          1|   2020|  202012|   1|     1|
|          1|   2020|  202012|   0|     0|
|          1|   2021|  202103|   0|     0|
|          1|   2021|  202106|   0|     0|
|          1|   2021|  202112|   1|     1|
|          2|   2020|  202006|   0|     0|
|          2|   2020|  202012|   0|     0|
|          2|   2020|  202012|   1|     1|
|          2|   2021|  202103|   0|     0|
|          2|   2021|  202106|   0|     0|
|          2|   2021|  202112|   1|     1|
+-----------+-------+--------+----+------+
```

Comment: can you do a `max()` of `dt_rfrnc` column to find the last row?

Comment: there could be duplicates (Added now), in which casae a random row can be tagged (but only one)

Comment: Whats the original input df?

Comment: the first three columns

Comment: you could use a `row_number()` window with descending sort and then mark wherever it is 1 -- so, if row_number is 1 then 1 else 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's  a way to achieve it with `row_number()`.

```
data_ls = [
    (1,2020,202006,0),
    (1,2020,202012,1),
    (1,2020,202012,0),
    (1,2021,202103,0),
    (1,2021,202106,0),
    (1,2021,202112,1),
    (2,2020,202006,0),
    (2,2020,202012,0),
    (2,2020,202012,1),
    (2,2021,202103,0),
    (2,2021,202106,0),
    (2,2021,202112,1)
]

sdf = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data_ls).toDF(['bvdidnumber', 'dt_year', 'dt_rfrnc', 'goal'])

# +-----------+-------+--------+----+
# |bvdidnumber|dt_year|dt_rfrnc|goal|
# +-----------+-------+--------+----+
# |          1|   2020|  202006|   0|
# |          1|   2020|  202012|   1|
# |          1|   2020|  202012|   0|
# |          1|   2021|  202103|   0|
# |          1|   2021|  202106|   0|
# |          1|   2021|  202112|   1|
# |          2|   2020|  202006|   0|
# |          2|   2020|  202012|   0|
# |          2|   2020|  202012|   1|
# |          2|   2021|  202103|   0|
# |          2|   2021|  202106|   0|
# |          2|   2021|  202112|   1|
# +-----------+-------+--------+----+

sdf. \
    withColumn('marker', 
               func.when(func.row_number().over(wd.partitionBy(['bvdidnumber', 'dt_year']).orderBy(func.desc('dt_rfrnc'))) == 1, 1).
               otherwise(0)
               ). \
    show()

# +-----------+-------+--------+----+------+
# |bvdidnumber|dt_year|dt_rfrnc|goal|marker|
# +-----------+-------+--------+----+------+
# |          1|   2021|  202112|   1|     1|
# |          1|   2021|  202106|   0|     0|
# |          1|   2021|  202103|   0|     0|
# |          2|   2021|  202112|   1|     1|
# |          2|   2021|  202106|   0|     0|
# |          2|   2021|  202103|   0|     0|
# |          1|   2020|  202012|   1|     1|
# |          1|   2020|  202012|   0|     0|
# |          1|   2020|  202006|   0|     0|
# |          2|   2020|  202012|   0|     1|
# |          2|   2020|  202012|   1|     0|
# |          2|   2020|  202006|   0|     0|
# +-----------+-------+--------+----+------+
```

As mentioned in your comment, if there are duplicates a random row is tagged but only one of them is tagged. Hence, there is a slight difference in the `goal` and `marker` -- the row is a duplicate.

> there could be duplicates (Added now), in which case a random row can be tagged (but only one)

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import max, struct, lit

# create data
schema = ["bvdidnumber","dt_year","dt_rfrnc","goal","marker"]
data = [(1,2020,202006,0,0),
(1,2020,202012,1,1),
(1,2020,202012,0,0),
(1,2021,202103,0,0),
(1,2021,202106,0,0),
(1,2021,202112,1,1),
(2,2020,202006,0,0),
(2,2020,202012,0,0),
(2,2020,202012,1,1),
(2,2021,202103,0,0),
(2,2021,202106,0,0),
(2,2021,202112,1,1),
]
df = spark.createDataFrame( data, schema )

df\
 .select(
   #get max this will sort data based on first column of struct
   struct( # create struct to carry all data forward - (think column with columns)
    col("dt_rfrnc"), # must be first to ensure your sort on this column
    col("dt_year"), 
    col("bvdidnumber")
   ).alias("columns")
   
  )\
  .groupby( 
   col("columns.bvdidnumber"),
   col("columns.dt_year"))
  .agg( 
   arrays_zip( #merge arrays in indexed manner
    expr("concat(array_repeat(1, 1), array_repeat( 0 , size(collect_list( columns ))-1 ) ) "), #Build array of 1's and zerps'
    reverse( #sort descending
     sort_array( #sort 
      collect_list( "columns" )))).alias("zip") )\ #collect group elements
  .select( 
   col("bvdidnumber") , 
   col("dt_year"), 
   explode("zip") )\#use array values as rows
  .select(
   col("bvdidnumber") , 
   col("dt_year"),
   col("col.`0`")\# funny column reference required for working with arrays_zip output
    .alias("marked")),\
   col("col.`1`.dt_rfrnc").alias("dt_rfrnc")
  .show()
+-----------+-------+------+--------+
|bvdidnumber|dt_year|marked|dt_rfrnc|
+-----------+-------+------+--------+
|          1|   2021|     1|  202112|
|          1|   2021|     0|  202106|
|          1|   2021|     0|  202103|
|          2|   2021|     1|  202112|
|          2|   2021|     0|  202106|
|          2|   2021|     0|  202103|
|          1|   2020|     1|  202012|
|          1|   2020|     0|  202012|
|          1|   2020|     0|  202006|
|          2|   2020|     1|  202012|
|          2|   2020|     0|  202012|
|          2|   2020|     0|  202006|
+-----------+-------+------+--------+
```

Comment: the goal was to create a new column

Comment: OK added a new column

Answer (score 0):

Cant see anything you have done wrong. Maybe just make it neater;

```
w=Window.partitionBy('bvdidnumber','dt_year').orderBy('bvdidnumber','dt_year')

df.withColumn('rand', when(sum((last('dt_rfrnc').over(w)==col('dt_rfrnc')).cast('int')).over(w.rowsBetween(-1,0))==1,1).otherwise(0)).show()

+-----------+-------+--------+----+
|bvdidnumber|dt_year|dt_rfrnc|rand|
+-----------+-------+--------+----+
|          1|   2020|  202006|   0|
|          1|   2020|   20201|   1|
|          1|   2020|   20201|   0|
|          1|   2021|  202103|   0|
|          1|   2021|  202106|   0|
|          1|   2021|  202112|   1|
|          2|   2020|  202006|   0|
|          2|   2020|   20201|   1|
|          2|   2020|   20201|   0|
|          2|   2021|  202103|   0|
|          2|   2021|  202106|   0|
|          2|   2021|  202112|   1|
+-----------+-------+--------+----+
```